# PL/SQL - Can't create package because of my function

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-navigator

Im trying to create a package and it works with procedures-only. As soon as I try to add a function following errors appear:

```
    15:47:11  line 1: ORA-24344: success with compilation error
15:47:11  14/3    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TITLE" when expecting one of the following:
15:47:11            . @ % ; is default authid as cluster order using external
15:47:11            character deterministic parallel_enable pipelined aggregate
15:47:11            result_cache accessible rewrite
15:47:11            The symbol ";" was substituted for "TITLE" to continue.
```

My code:

```
create or replace package job_pkg is

  procedure add_job 
  (jobid jobs_test.job_id%type, jobtitle jobs_test.job_title%type);
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  procedure upd_job 
  (alt jobs_test.job_id%type, neu jobs_test.job_id%type);
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  procedure del_job 
  (jobid jobs_test.job_id%type);
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  function get_job
  (id jobs_test.job_id%type) return varchar2 
  title jobs_test.job_title%type;

end job_pkg;
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just put semicolon after `return varchar2` as it is just the declaration of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon.

```
  function get_job
  (id jobs_test.job_id%type) return varchar2;

  title jobs_test.job_title%type;
```

Assuming you're creating a package level variable 'title' AND declaring your function spec here.

Comment: the error message is somewhat understandable "15:47:11            The symbol ";" was substituted for "TITLE" to continue." the compiler had to add the ';' for you, and it happened when it saw the identifier, 'TITLE'. Your IDE should have given you a local parser warning/indicator as to where the issue lied - SQL Developer definitely would have.